# Windows ssh agent forwarding and cap\git deploy problems

Tags: git, ssh, capistrano, openssh

Capistrano fails to connect to git repo (bitbucket) with ssh agent forwarding from windows.

**Environment:**

```
Windows 10
Ruby 2.4.4 for Windows installed
Rails 5.2.2
Cap 3.11.0
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1
```

Can successfully ssh to host and `git ls-remote` or `clone`. When issuing a cap deploy or cap task like `git ls-remote` connecting to the bitbucket repo fails.

```
git stdout: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
git stderr: Nothing written
```

Capistrano does connect to the bitbucket repo if using http and setting the username:password in the URL.

I have written cap tasks to show that `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set. I have played with `.ssh\config` with many options pointing to the keys, `host *` etc.

**deploy.rb:**

`set :repo_url` set correctly.

**staging.rb**

```
set :ssh_options,
    keys: ['c:\users\mike\.ssh\key.pem'],
    forward_agent: true
```

**.ssh\config**

```
Host hostname
  User username
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.pem
  ForwardAgent yes
```

**/etc/ssh/sshd.conf on server**

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

Looking for advice on what to try next. It seems cap is using the wrong public key or failing to use agent forwarding. I have added all the keys to bitbucket also and that didn't work.

### Additional findings:

*Monitoring /var/log/secure during a cap deploy yeilds this*

Seems it cannot connect to the ssh-agent on the source computer.

```
Feb 18 23:13:15 ip-255-255-255-255 sshd[19242]: Accepted publickey for railsuser from x.x.x.x port 60682 ssh2: RSA SHA256:<has>
Feb 18 23:13:15 ip-255-255-255-255 sshd[19242]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user railsuser by (uid=0)
Feb 18 23:13:15 ip-255-255-255-255 sshd[19260]: channel 2: open failed: connect failed: could not connect to authentication agent
Feb 18 23:13:15 ip-255-255-255-255 sshd[19242]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user railsuser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano uses the [net-ssh](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) gem and net-ssh doesn't currently support Windows native installation of OpenSSH.

Net-ssh does support [Putty's pageant](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) or [Cygwin's](https://www.cygwin.com/) ssh-agent installation.

I have successfully tested Putty's pageant and it worked as expected.

Comment: To expand on the above you will install `pageant.exe`, no need for the main putty app. Also if you are converting an ssh-2 key you will need to install `puttygen.exe` and import your old key, save that converted key and import it into pageant.